# How can I reformat php's old "array()" to the newer/neater "[]" with Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a neat search and replace model for reformatting php's old `array` style to the newer/cleaner json style - without reformatting the entire document with a formatter extension*

### from

```
$flibble = array('foo' => 'bar');

$wibble = array(
    'linefeeds' => true,
);
```

### to

```
$flibble = ['foo' => 'bar'];


$wibble = [
    'linefeeds' => true,
];
```

`*` *Aside; I can't actually find a PHP Formatter for VSC which does this either...*

Comment: hey @Jim Morrison, you've found a solution for vscode meanwhile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No idea how to do it with visual studio code itself but here are some solutions:

---

Using PHP Codesniffer:

https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer

```
phpcbf src/ --standard=Generic --sniffs=Generic.Arrays.DisallowLongArraySyntax
```

or

https://github.com/thomasbachem/php-short-array-syntax-converter

Answer (score 1):

There is now a vscode plugin:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Yannick.php-convert-array

I haven't tried it.

Comment: Works nicely.. Many thanks to you and the developer.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone will need it, for VSCode, find and replace in Regex mode with the following Regex in the following order:

1. Find and replace `array(...)` that are written on the same line with

   - find: `([^in_|is_])array\(([^)])*)\)`
   - and replace with: `$1[$2]`
2. Find and replace `array(...)` that are written on more than one line with

   - find: `([^in_|is_])array\((([^;)]|[\r\n])*)\)`
   - and replace with: `$1[$2]`

Be carefull with the 2nd Regex. This will not find array value that contains a closing parenthesis `)`.
Never find and replace all occurrences in one shot. Check each found occurrence before applying replacement.